# Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String' error

Tags: swift, xcode

I receive the following error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of
>   type 'String'

on this line of code:

```
let temp = Int (weatherMain["temp"] as? Double ?? 0)
```

I'm a beginner in Xcode please help

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Can you please share your full code?

Comment: @shony does my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the type as `[String: Any]`
Where you should cast as `[[String: Any]]`

Something like:

```
let temp = Int (weatherMain[0]["temp"] as? Double ?? 0)
```

You need to pass index.

Answer (score 1):

`weatherMain` is an array of dictionaries. I dont know how you are storing the data, but to access the `["temp"]` value, you need to do `weatherMain[0]["temp"]` where 0 is the index.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of
>   type 'String'

`[[String : Any]]` is an `Array` of `Dictionaries` and `Array` is accessible through `Int` indexes and not `String`.

So, you need to first fetch the `Dictionary` from `Array` using `Int` index and then access key-value pair from that `Dictionary` using `String`.

```
let temp = Int (weatherMain["temp"] as? Double ?? 0)
```

In the above code, assuming that `weatherMain` is of type [[String : Any]], to access key "temp" from a `Dictionary`, you need to first fetch that `dictionary` from the `array`, i.e.

```
let dict = weatherMain[0]
let temp = Int(dict["temp"] as? Double ?? 0)
```